# SiteCore development with VS Code

Tags: sitecore, visual-studio-code

I have a crazy requirement.  Is it possible to develop SiteCore solutions using VS Code?  My SiteCore solution is fairly large and VS hangs from time to time when I do simple things.  I am quite amazed at the speed with which VS code works and was wondering if there are any add ins or something like that which I can use to develop SiteCore solutions?

Comment: VS Code isn't really designed for an undertaking this significant, but it might be technically possible with enough effort.  My guess is that if VS.Net hangs due to the complexity of your "large" solution then you'll have no fun trying to get VSCode to work.  Have you tried disabling ReSharper.  That works better than 50% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got me thinking, so I did a bit of additional research.
Turns out this is not actually even technically possible at this time, for the following reasons:

1. VS Code does not support debugging applications running on the Desktop .NET Framework - do you feel like you can write your Sitecore site without a debugger?
2. ASP.NET MVC applications are not recognised by VS Code, though ASP.NET Core is supported

Also it seems that there is no "multi-project" support, so forget about Helix principles.

VS Code is really designed to be a lightweight editor and is not really up for this task.  I suggest you take a look at Visual Studio 2017 which has lazy loaded projects now, and enough refactoring tools built right in that you can afford to add fewer addins.  This should make your editing environment much more responsive.

I have several solutions with over 100 projects in VS2015 Pro and it's really not that big an issue (though I do have a decent desktop PC with an i7 and SSDs).